# QT connect signal and slot in from different classes to mainwindow class?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I want to implement signal and slot between two classes `mainwindow` and `reader`.

Inside the `reader` class I declare the signal `SetProgress`:

reader.h

```
class reader :public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT    
         signals:
             void SetProgress(QString sOperation, int nPercentage);
}
```

reader.cpp

```
 void reader::UpdateProgress(double amount)
{
     int nPrecentage = (100 * amount / (max- min));
     emit SetProgress(m_sCurrentOperation, nPrecentage); 
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
    public:
    reader *MyReader

private slots:

    void SlotDisplayProgress(QString sActivity_i, int ProgressPercentage_i);
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
void mainwindow :: SlotDisplayProgress(QString sActivity_i, int nProgressPercentage_i)
{
     this->ui->QprogressBar->setValue(nProgressPercentage_i);
}
```

inside Mainwidow.cpp I will declare signal and slot

```
MyReader = reader::New();
connect ( MyReader, &reader::SetProgress, this, &mainwindow::SlotDisplayProgress );
```

I tried debugging and everything works correctly till the `emit` part. However, the `slot` is never executed.

Comment: What exception?

Comment: Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE1A48063A (Qt5Cored.dll) in mainwindow.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Comment: Seems like `MyReader` is an invalid pointer.

Comment: I will make object inside the mainwindow.cpp (reader *MyReader)

Comment: You still have to assign a valid value to your pointer. `reader *Myreader;` Doesn't assign any valid value to your pointer.

Comment: sorry, I am not getting. could you explain what valid value assign to the pointer

Comment: `reader *MyReader = new reader()`

Comment: I'm going to guess you're pretty new to `C++`?

Comment: @AmarKumar, debug your code and show where it crashes.

Comment: Sorry I will forget to assign value ( MyReader = reader :: New();) . Now, my emit function not passing the value to signal and slot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting Qt::DirectConnection:

```
connect ( MyReader, &reader::SetProgress, this, &mainwindow::SlotDisplayProgress, ***Qt::DirectConnection***);
```

I had a problem like this, where I connected the signal and slot, and it only worked when I defined the type of connection.

I hope this helps.

---

PS. I don't know if this depends on the version of QT but when I connect signals and slots the syntax I write is the following:

```
ImageURLLoadListener* downloader = new ImageURLLoadListener(&id, socket);
connect(downloader, SIGNAL(imageLoaded(QString*,QTcpSocket*)), this, SLOT(on_resourceImageDownload(QString*,QTcpSocket*)), Qt::DirectConnection);
```

I don't know if it's related or not...

Answer (score 0):

Is MyReader pointer? Use &MyReader if not so.

Comment: I am getting this one error,  after applying &Myreader. Error E0304no instance of overloaded function "mainwindow::connect" matches the argument list

Comment: SetProgress and SlotDisplayProgress require 2 arguments, try using: connect ( &MyReader, SIGNAL(SetProgress(QString,int)), this, SLOT(SlotDisplayProgress(QString,int));

Comment: Show all the associated code for a quick fix. (reader class in reader.h, skip non associated function and members)

Comment: @deMax, the OP has a runtime error. The code would not compile if _MyReader_ weren't a pointer.

Comment: How you create MyReader object?  Show more code. ( reader *MyReader = new MyReader; ) ?

Comment: It is going till emit part correctly. However, it is not reaching the slot. and my reader object  is (*MyReader = reader :: New();)